# Assign this magic number 5 to a well-named constant, and use the constant instead

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am getting below error from SONAR and i am really not understand with what changes below issues will be resolved can some one suggest me please

### Class

```
 @Component
    public class CatalogRequestValidator {
        
        public void validateBaseOffersReq(CatalogRequest baseOffersRequest) {
            int ZIP_CODE_LENGTH=5;
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Make `ZIP_CODE_LENGTH` a class-constant (looks like it was one at some point in time, but was then inlined for some reason). This will get rid of the second warning as well.

Comment: Well, Java has Naming Conventions: variable names and method names are written in camelCase and class names in PascalCase. SNAKE_CASE is used for *constants*, that is, variables marked `static final`. Your `ZIP_CODE_LENGTH` variable looks like it is a constant, according to the Java Naming Conventions, but it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

a constant in this context is a `public static final` field in a class, not a method variable.

Comment: @Component
    public class CatalogRequestValidator {
        public static final int ZIP_CODE_LENGTH=5;
        public void validateBaseOffersReq(CatalogRequest baseOffersRequest) {
            
        }
    }

Comment: you mean i have to define like above

Comment: @AbhiRam no, not as a method parameter / argument, you need to declare a constant (`static final`) `int` at class level.

Comment: @AbhiRam what's above is very hard to read, but yes - inside the class, outside of the method.

Answer (score 1):

The first sonar advice means that the format of your local variable ZIP_CODE_LENGTH is wrong, according to standards. It should be zipCodeLength (camelCase).

The second advice means that the number 5 should be assigned to a constant.

In order to solve both advices just define the local variable as a constant outside the method (private or public).

```
private static final int ZIP_CODE_LENGTH=5;
```